# Duplicate rows in the database when refreshing the page laravel

Tags: database, laravel

there is a page which is updated every 5-7 seconds, and on it records from the base are updated, but moments these records are duplicated, Do not tell me why this bug can be?

is a ActiveCaller model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class ActiveCaller extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['queue', 'employee_id', 'station', 'state', 'duration',
        'client_id', 'last_call'];

    public function Employee()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Employee::class);
    }

    /**
     * Convert duration attribute to acceptable format
     *
     * @param $value
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDurationAttribute($value)
    {
        if (empty($value))
            return $value;

        return $this->sec2hms($value);
    }

    public function getStateAttribute($value)
    {
        if (!empty($value))
            return trim($value);

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Convert last call attribute to acceptable format
     *
     * @param $value
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLastCallAttribute($value)
    {
        $data = explode("\n", $value);

        $result = "";
        $i = 0;
        $len = count($data) - 1;

        foreach ($data as $item) {
            $item = str_replace("\r", "", $item);
            $delimiter = "</br>";
            if ($i == $len)
                $delimiter = "";

            if (empty($item) || (trim($item) == "No calls yet")) {
                $result .= "No calls yet$delimiter";
            } else {
                $result .= $this->sec2hms($item) . " min. ago $delimiter";
            }

            $i++;
        }

        return $result;
    }

    public function getStationAttribute($value)
    {
        return str_replace("\r\n", "</br>", $value);
    }

    private function sec2hms($sec, $padHours = FALSE)
    {
        $timeStart = Carbon::now();
        $timeEnd = Carbon::now()->addSeconds(intval($sec));

        return  $timeStart->diff($timeEnd)->format('%H:%I:%S');
    }
}
```

is a AmiApiController

```
class AmiApiController extends Controller
{
    public function fetchDashboardData()
    {
        $this->updateQueueState();

        $activeCallers = ActiveCaller::with('Employee')
            ->where('old', true)
            ->orderBy('queue')
            ->orderBy('employee_id')
            ->orderBy('station', 'asc')
            ->get();


        $waitingList = WaitingList::where('old', false)->get();
        $waitingList = $waitingList->unique('client_id');

        $charts = Chart::all()->toArray();

        $chartFormatData = [
            'Total' => [],
            'Callers' => [],
            'Queues' => [],
        ];

        foreach ($charts as $key => $chart) {
            $charts[$key]['data'] = json_decode($chart['data'], 1);
            $chartFormatData[$chart['name']]['total'] = 0;
            foreach ($charts[$key]['data']['statistic'] as $datum) {
//                if ($datum[0] === 'Effort')
//                    continue;

                $chartFormatData[$chart['name']]['label'][] = $datum[0];
                $chartFormatData[$chart['name']]['data'][] = $datum[1];
                $chartFormatData[$chart['name']]['name'] = $chart['name'];
            }
            $chartFormatData[$chart['name']]['total'] = array_sum($chartFormatData[$chart['name']]['data']);
//            $chartFormatData[$chart['name']]['label'] = array_reverse($chartFormatData[$chart['name']]['label']);
        }

        return response()->json([
            'activeCallers' => $activeCallers,
            'charts' => $chartFormatData,
            'waitingList' => $waitingList
        ], 200);
    }
```

this is where we begin to check if we can update the database at this time

```
      /**
         * Check whether the database can be updated at this time
         *
         *  - Returns True if no updates are currently being made to the database
         *     and the latest update was less than 5 seconds later
         *  - 
Returns True if the update already occurs for more than 15 seconds
         *
         *  - Returns False if an update is already in the database
         *  - 
Returns False if the last update was within the last 5 seconds
         *
         *  If the parameter in $ json is passed true (by default)
         *  the method returns the answer in JSON format
         *
         *  If the parameter is passed false to $ json
         * method returns a php-shne Boolean value
         *
         * @param bool $json
         * @return bool|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
         */
        public function canWeUpdate($json = true)
        {
            $result = ['return' => null, 'msg' => null];

            $isUpdating = Configuration::where('key', 'is_ami_data_updating')->first();

            if (is_null($isUpdating)) {
                Configuration::create(['key' => 'is_ami_data_updating', 'value' => 0]);
            }

            if ($isUpdating->value == true) {
                // if an update is currently in progress
                $checkingDate = Carbon::now()->addSeconds(-10);
                if ($isUpdating->updated_at < $checkingDate) {
                    // if the update is longer than 15 seconds, we will cancel this update
                    $isUpdating->update(['value' => false]);
                    $result['return'] = true;
                    $result['msg'] = "Old update in database";
                } else {
                    // if the update is less than 15 seconds, we cannot update again
                    $result['return'] = false;
                    $result['msg'] = "CURRENTLY UPDATE";
                }
            } else if ($isUpdating->updated_at > Carbon::now()->addSeconds(-3)) {
                // if the last update was less than 5 seconds ago, we cannot update
                $result['return'] = false;
                $result['msg'] = "TOO EARLY";
            } else {
                //if the last update was more than 5 seconds ago, we allow the update
                $result['return'] = true;
                $result['msg'] = "OK";
            }

            if ($json)
                return $this->simpleResponse($result['return'], $result['msg']);

            return $result['return'];
        }
```

is a method fot check if new data is in the database

```
        /**
         * A method to check if new data is in the database
         *
         * Returns True if validation time is less than database update time
         * Returns False if validation time is longer than database update time
         * Returns False if there is no data in the database
         *
         * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
         */
        public function checkForNewData(Request $request)
        {
            $date = new Carbon($request->last_call);
            $lastRecord = ActiveCaller::latest()->first();

            if (is_null($lastRecord))
                return $this->simpleResponse(false);

            if ($date < $lastRecord->updated_at) {
                return $this->simpleResponse(true);
            } else
                return $this->simpleResponse(false);
        }

        /**
         * Method for loading table data
         *
         * Agents - information about active numbers in the PBX in all queues
         * Waiting - information about numbers in standby mode
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
         */
        public function renderAgentTable()
        {
            $agents = ActiveCaller::with('Employee')
                ->where('old', true)
                ->orderBy('queue')
                ->orderBy('station', 'asc')
                ->get();

            $waitingList = WaitingList::all();

            $agentsTable = View::make('dashboard.render.agent-table', ['agents' => $agents]);
            $waitingTable = View::make('dashboard.render.waiting-list-table', ['waitingList' => $waitingList]);

            $result =
                [
                    'agents' => $agentsTable->render(),
                    'waiting' => $waitingTable->render(),
                ];

            $result = array_merge($result, $this->renderDashboardChart(new Request()));

            return response()->json($result);
        }

        /**
         * Method for updating data from AMI
         *
         * updating data for ActiveCaller
         * updating data for WaitingList
         */
        public function updateQueueState()
        {
            if (!$this->canWeUpdate(false)) {
    //            dd("We can't update (large check)");
                return;
            }

            $lastUpdateTime = ActiveCaller::latest()->first();

            if ($lastUpdateTime != null)
                if ($lastUpdateTime->created_at > Carbon::now()->addSeconds(-3)) {
    //                dd("We can't update (small check)");
                    return;
                }

            // we notice the launch of the update in the database
            $isAmiDataUpdating = Configuration::where('key', 'is_ami_data_updating')->first();
            $isAmiDataUpdating->update(['value' => true]);

            $this->ClearOldRecords();

            $queues = Queue::where('on_dashboard', '=', '1')->get()->toArray();
            // we go through all the queues that are available in AMI
            foreach ($queues as $queue) {
                $command = new AMIQueueMemberState($queue['name']);

                // we get a list of numbers and a waiting list of calls
                $response = $command->handle();
                $agents = $response['agents'];
                $callers = $response['callers'];

                //convert the waiting list to PeerList
                $peerList = PeerInfo::hydrate($agents);
                $employees = new Collection();

                foreach ($callers as $caller) {
                    $caller['queue'] = $queue['name'];
                    WaitingList::create($caller);
                }

                $peerList->each(function (PeerInfo $peer) use ($employees) {
                    $record = Record
                        ::where('phone', 'like', '%' . $peer->name . '%')
                        ->where('end_date', null)
                        ->get()->first();

                    $data = null;
                    if ($record != null) {
                        // check if this user already has an entry in active_callers (not old)
                        $active = ActiveCaller
                            ::where('employee_id', $record['employee_id'])
                            ->where('old', false)
                            ->get()->first();

                        // if so, add him another number and
                        // we move on to the next iteration
                        if ($active != null) {

                           if ($this->HandleSingleActive($active, $peer->name, $peer->last_call))

                                return;
                        }


                        $peer->station = $record['station_name'];
                        $peer->employee_id = $record['employee_id'];

                        $a = collect($peer->toArray());
                        $data = $a->except(['name', 'pause'])->toArray();
                        $data['station'] = "$peer->station | $peer->name";
                    } else {
                        $peer->station = "- | $peer->name";
                        $a = collect($peer->toArray());
                        $data = $a->except(['name', 'pause'])->toArray();
                    }
                    ActiveCaller::create($data);
                });
            }

            $this->updateDashboardChart();

            $isAmiDataUpdating->update(['value' => false]);
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Whatever is causing the data to be duplicated doesn't seem to live within the code you have posted. We would need to see more context to help you solve this problem. If you are certain the duplication is linked to this code, then the issue might be with something on one of the models being referenced here.

Comment: @JamesClarkDeveloper
i was editing the post, i would be very grateful if you could look over this code and help solve this duplicate issue

Comment: does it duplicate in the database itself? are there two records for one entry? or does it just show up twice on the page?

Comment: @maximus1127 it duplicate in the database itself

Comment: @maximus1127  like when, sometimes two records, sometimes three records

Comment: @maximus1127 I added a screenshot, you can see how it goes on the page

Comment: If you have duplicate data, i would be very interested in $peerList = PeerInfo::hydrate($agents); as with the code you have provided as of know is the only way to duplicate data. Secondly couldnt it be a racing condition with your process being called twice?

Comment: @mrhn do you mean replacing this line of code?$peerList = PeerInfo::hydrate($agents);
there are times when the checkfornewdata process is called twice or three times

Comment: I want to know what that line does and returns. You have one place where you have a CREATE() method. That is wrapped in a loop. Return of peerInfo dictates how many times it creates something.

Meanwhile, couldn't it be that your logic is called multiple times?

Comment: @mrhn as far as I understand,this line fills a new collection object with models from an $agents

sorry, I just didn't develop this project from the beginning,
and I also do not fully understand everything

Comment: @mrhn in general, this call center project and to $agents recording call waiting list